# Excel - export in a new sheet only the cells values that respect a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm going to explain my problem.

In the USERS column there are users ID that I have to copy into another Excel sheet only if in the REQUEST column there is the word "Creation", but if, in a later row, the same user ID has in the REQUEST column the word "Elimination", the very same user has to disappear from the second Excel sheet. I've just tried with Pivot table, INDEX, MATCH formula but I don't have success.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FILTER()` Function, assuming you are using `MS365`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=FILTER(A2:C5,B2:B5<>"Deletion")
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `I2`

```
=FILTER(A2:C5,B2:B5="Creation")
```

---

Edit --> Excluding Eliminated

[image]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,(B2:B7<>"Deletion")*(B2:B7<>"Eliminated"))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `I2`

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="Creation")
```

Comment: thank's for the answer. I've just tried with the filter function, but I need also that if a user, that was created in the past, changes his status to "Eliminated", this user has to disappear from the second Excel sheet

Comment: Yes that should also, disappear once the request column for the said user is changed to deletion, i think that should work, could you try once and let me know

Comment: @aleMara please see the edit in my answer

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work:( I need that all the users with the tag "creation" is going to copy in a new Excel sheet, but when a user already present with the tag "creation", is added in the list with the tag "Deletion"; this very user disappear from the new Excel sheet

Comment: @aleMara you can see in the screenshot it is working, could you show me screengrab or share a copy of the workbook using any cloud storage link

Comment: Sorry but i've a hard time explaining what I want

Comment: @aleMara it should update because its a dynamic formula, could you share me a onedrive link of the workbook

Comment: I can't share the file because my IT policy firm doesn't permit it

Comment: But if you see in your screen, IT01336 is tagged as "Eliminated" but it still remain in the table with the filter

Comment: Ok, but see if you are trying to make those cells disappear, on the sheet which are already being brought from sheet 1 as "Creation" and now you are editing in the sheet 2 as "Deletion", this wont work, and its totally a different query which doesnt match what you have explained in your original post

Comment: Columns `E2:G7` & Columns `I2:K7` are the outputs excluding "Deletion" & "Elimination", while the Column Range `A2:C7` is the actual data which is in sheet 1 and you have mentioned that in sheet 2 both deletion and elimination employees should not be carries

Comment: ok, I understand your solution but it works only if I modify the same row where the user was created. I tried to explain myself better: in the first sheet I've to put the USER ID with his status ("Creation" or "Deletion"), if a user change his status from Creation to Deletion, I've to insert this in a new row. In a second sheet, I want an export only the USERID  that has in the status the word "Creation", but if in the future, in sheet 1, there will be a new row with this USERID with the status "deletion", the USERID in the sheet 2 must be disappear

Comment: @aleMara alright, can we do one thing, I am sharing a one drive link of the copy of the workbook, could you make changes there. and show me.

Comment: @aleMara please refer this one drive link [Query](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2chWBAObz3_PqH9jlB?e=wHR4Zm)

Comment: I've added USER it01338 in the first sheet with the tag "Deletion", I've updated the file, but in the second sheet the user it01338 still remains

Comment: @aleMara please check now I have updated the formula

Comment: Top, great job. But if I add another row with the same userid (the third row with the same user) and the tag "Creation", it doesn't work. I'm sorry of challenge you like this:(

Comment: Ok, updated again using power query, please check

Comment: I've taken a look at the file, it seems to work as I want, thank you very much. I've only to understand how the power query works. I'll try and I let you know. In the mean time thank you very much for your work